# turn client library for connecting to turn server

Tags: stun, turn

I am planning to use turn protocol for communication between Arduino peer and a linux host. Both are behind NAT and direct communication is not possible.

As i understand, i can utilise turn protocol, and setup a turn server to relay between client and peer.

However, i have hard time finding a suitable library in NodeJS/Java/Python that will let me implement the client side of turn.

What i am looking for, is a turn client library.

Any recommendation / suggestion will be helpful.